# Do received UDP packets queued in LwIP stack?

Tags: c, lwip

I am writing a **C** program using **LwIP** with **FreeRTOS** for an embedded device, the micro-controller is Atmel AVR32.

In *LwIP*, after setting up the *udp* receive callback function by `udp_recv()`, I know that the callback function will be called once an *UDP* datagram is received. Then I can do something like `process_udp_packet()` inside the callback function. However, if there is another *UDP* packet received before the callback function finished, will this second packet queued in a buffer? Or the callback function will be called again immediately, even the first callback function is not finished?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callback is called in context of LwIP itself. So, until you exit from callback, LwIP will be blocked. It will not process any new packets at all. 
If there will be arriving new data, interface driver should not read it from interface (like modem) or save it in own buffer, until LwIP will be unblocked.

So, callback should exit as soon as possible to do not interfere normal LwIP workflow.
Best approach in programming of such callback functions is to read new packet into app queue and immediately return from callback. Then app in its own context can process new data.

But, if data processing is done really fast, you can do it inside callback function.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I also find that it is not suitable to do too many things inside the callback because the callback input parameters are not really suitable for me. So now I just allocated a buffer to store the packet (because I know that a real packet could be stored in a link of pbuf structure and the header of the pbuf is not real data). However, by doing so, I need to poll to check whether a packet is received, is it correct? I worry that this is not good because actually I am doing a VoIP project with RTP support, so real-time is important. Could you advise?

Comment: Also, I would like to ask whether the **len** field in the struct pbuf represents the length of payload or the length of a whole pbuf? The comment in the code said the former. However when I check the function **pbuf_header()**, it seems that *len* represent the length of whole pbuf.....thank you @werewindle

Comment: @eepty, If you you're creating realtime VoIP project, I recommend you to use some RT tasker (i.e. Keil RTOS, or FreeRTOS). This will allow you to have many threads in realtime environment. In your case, thread that wait for new packet will not poll it. It will just blocked on semaphore. When new packet arrives, callback saves it to a buffer and signals to the semaphore. This unlocks processing thread.. Meantime (when there are no new packets), your device can execute other low priority threads, like interacting with user.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am using FreeRTOS, I will take your advise and see how to improve the software. Actually I have succeeded to send and received data by RTP with LwIP, but now I want to implement the SIP and I have a question of the eXosip2 SIP stack, I will ask in a separated post, if you have experience of it, please kindly advise, thank you.